# Android WebView HTML5 canvas error

Tags: android, html, webview, html5-canvas, chart.js

I have an Android application which uses WebView to load the GUI using HTML. There is a <canvas> element into which i draw charts using Chart.js Javascript library for plotting charts. 
It was tested on 3 devices. On two of them it works fine (Android 2.2 and 2.6), but on a later vesion of android (4.1.2) the canvas makes it double: all the charts are visible twice in the canvas, one of them is shifted a bit up and to the left.

[image: canvas with double chart]

What is the problem with the canvas? Why does it double the things rendered? How can i made it render only once?

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="graph_canvas"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("graph_canvas");
canvas.height=200;
canvas.width=200;
var graphSelection=document.getElementById("graphSelection");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data_=JSON.parse(JI.getGraphData(graphSelection.value));    
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data_);
```

Where graphSelection is a <select> element with which we select the chart,
JI.getGraphData returns JSON data for Chart.js.

Comment: Try to make the graph position fixed, via style tag, into the canvas html code

Comment: that worked. it messed some other things, but the graph works. thanks!

Comment: now a new problem appeared, i posted it under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847582/chart-js-canvas-resize

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want problems caused by "position: fixed;" on element,
canvas parent element should not have css property "overflow" with value "hidden".

So define something like "overflow: visible;" on parent element.

Comment: Actually I solved a similar problem by setting `overflow: hidden;` to the canvas's parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// If Samsung android browser is detected
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('534.30') > 0) {

    // Tweak the canvas opacity, causing it to redraw
    $('canvas').css('opacity', '0.99');

    // Set the canvas opacity back to normal after 5ms
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('canvas').css('opacity', '1');
    }, 5);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too. I solved it by using `position:relative , left and -webkit-transform instead margin;`. The problem was solved accidentally.