# ChartJS keeps resizing canvas to the default size

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

Using the code below.

```
var canvas = $('<canvas/>').addClass('chart').appendTo(element);

// ...

canvas.css({ width: 700, height: 400 });
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
```

The canvas always gets resized to 300x150 when the last line is called. Why?

Comment: You will have more visitors if you tagged this with a main tag like `javascript`...

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847582/chart-js-canvas-resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles you apply via `css` are lost when you `getContext`. You should try using `prop` too/instead.

```
canvas.prop({ width: 700, height: 400 });
```