# Getting chart js bar chart to fill window

Tags: chart.js

I have a `chart js` bar chart that draws within the canvas:

```
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
```

However I would like the chart to fit the size of the current window. I have tried:

```
<canvas id="chart" width="100%" height="400"></canvas>
```

but it does not like it. I could get the window width using window.innerWidth but is there any reason why the 100% does not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see the post: [Chart.js canvas resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847582/chart-js-canvas-resize) . There are actually two answers that are really good solutions here. You can use the chart options like below:

```
// Boolean - whether or not the chart should be responsive and resize when the browser does.

responsive: true,

// Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container

maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

or you can set the canvas width and height using client side code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = 300;
ctx.canvas.height = 300;
var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData);
```

This post very effectively answers your question about why % values dont work: [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. Purely by accident I have found that by putting responsive:true in the options does the job perfectly.

Comment: Great, no problem. I had trouble with that same issue when starting to work with this library as well. Maybe you can mark this as an answer so others can use it as reference.

Answer (score 2):

After setting responsive and ratio options (check out related [chartjs doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html)), use following css to fill 100% of the parent:

html

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.panel {
  display: flex;

  .chart-container {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height: 0;
  }
}
```