# Chart.js pie chart in table shows weird behavior on page resize

Tags: html-table, chart.js

There are chart.js pie charts in a html table.
The issue:  on zoom-out and then zoom-in, the cells do not resize to their initial size.
The layout looks something like this:

```
 __________________________
|   inner div | inner div  |
|_____________|____________|
|             |            |
|  Pie1       |  Pie2      |
|_____________|____________|
```

I have referred the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html) on resizing and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847582/chart-js-canvas-resize) to add responsive and maintainAspectRatio fields in options object.  
On setting responsive:true, the diagram is enabled to resize on zoom.  
Setting maintainAspectRatio:false, to fix previous irregular zoom issue where the multiple charts do not resize proportionally since they take table cell's width.  
Just for reference there is a blurry text issue with chart.js zoom mentioned at
[github here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2814).

Sourcecode of issue on JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfaLvuho/.  
Use zoom-out and zoom-in back to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to `<div>` elements for the layout to fix this. I used `float` in the snippet below but it should work with `flex` or `grid` layout as well.

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};

chartColors = {
  red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
  yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
  green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
  blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
  purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
  grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};
var config = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        chartColors.red,
        chartColors.orange,
        chartColors.yellow,
        chartColors.green,
        chartColors.blue,
      ],
      label: 'Dataset 1'
    }],
    labels: [
      'Red',
      'Orange',
      'Yellow',
      'Green',
      'Blue'
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: false
  }
};

var myPie1 = new Chart('chart-area1', config);
var myPie2 = new Chart('chart-area2', config);
```

```css
.canvas-holder {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas-holder">
  <canvas id="chart-area1"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="canvas-holder">
  <canvas id="chart-area2"></canvas>
</div>
```