# Chart.js canvas resize of pie / doughnut chart

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I have created an doughnut chart (`Chart.js`) in an `Bootstrap Panel`. Fore some reason the chart is only about 50% of the width of this panel.

I have found this topic: [Chart.js canvas resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847582/chart-js-canvas-resize) and changed `maintainAspectRatio: true` to `maintainAspectRatio: false`, but then the chart is not created / visible.

Any suggestions?

[image]

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Aandachtspunten</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

       <div class="container" style="position: relative; width:100%">
          <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [10, 20, 30],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                    'rgb(255, 206, 86)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
            labels: [
                'Red',
                'Yellow',
                'Blue'
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            legend: false,
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I save the image to my computer it has the dimension 284x142. Because the image and it's background  is not square I think I am having this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it is limited by its height, since it has reached the max height. You can try setting the width manually but it might not work if it always tries to make a perfect circle.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#important-note

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. When I save that image it is not square (284x142), I will update my post.

Comment: The image you download is the whole canvas, as you can see the chart is filling top to bottom from the image, so unless chart js allows you to make the doughnut into an eclipse (which I doubt because it is different math) you wont be able to get it to be the full width of the container

Comment: Even when I set the height of the container to `400px` I have the same problem.

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me if I set the dimensions of the container with CSS to a square: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/jbd08wt9/7/